# Redefine blank space in {cases}?

Tags: spacing, cases

By default, the `cases` environment adds some blank space between the end of the first part of the line and what's followed by `&` (unlike, say, `aligned` environment). I'm wondering what is the default value of this space, and if I can globally adjust it?

Comment: The space between the two parts of a line in the `cases` environment is hard coded as `\quad`.  Here is the relevant component of the definition: `\array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}`.  It could be redefined by patching, but if a change is wanted for only some instances of the environment, patching is not the best way.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As mentioned by barbara beeton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521512/redefine-blank-space-in-cases#comment1318777_521512), the default gap between the elements and their conditions within the `cases` environment is `\quad`. It stems from the following definition combinations in [`amsmath.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsmath.dtx):

```
\renewenvironment{cases}{%
  \matrix@check\cases\env@cases
}{%
  \endarray\right.%
}
\def\env@cases{%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrace
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}%
}
```

The `\env@cases` part uses a [vertically stretched `array`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764) that has two `l`eft-aligned columns, separated by `\quad`. For consistency, you can patch this definition and replace `\quad` with (say) `~`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\env@cases}% <cmd>
  {\quad}% <search>
  {~}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
     x & \text{if $x \geq 0$} \\
    -x & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

In the above image, the original spacing (with `\quad`) is shown at the top with the updated spacing (with `~`) at the bottom.

Comment: Cool!! Thank you.